# How to delete all blank lines in the file with the help of python?

Tags: python, text-processing

For example, we have some file like that:

```
first line
second line

third line
```

And in result we have to get:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

Use ONLY python

Comment: Share your ideas and attempts. We'll try to help you.

Comment: It's actually trivial with grep, eg. `grep -v '^$' file`

Comment: It should work both under win and linux, so we can use ONLY python, no grep =)

Comment: grep can also work on windows.

Comment: answer in: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145126/open-a-text-file-and-remove-any-blank-lines

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("file",inplace=1):
    if line.rstrip():
        print line
```

Comment: +1 for also catching lines that contain whitespace and nothing else.

Comment: This will change for formatting of whitespace even in the good lines

Comment: Markdown formatting utilises trailing spaces. Remove simple change to this answer would strip lines with just whitespace and preserve trailing spaces: `if line.rstrip(): print line`

Comment: @Thomas, and why would a field have an ending "\n" in a file? If a file has "\n", then i would bet its literal. If its really a "\n", then the next field will be on the next line. isn't that so? or am i still missing what you are saying? If its necessarily pls provide your explanation as an answer as the putting in comment is hard to read.

Comment: @ghostdog74 It's not about the line breaks, but about the tabs. If you cut the tabs from the end of each line, then each row in the table will not have the same number of columns.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly for me. If I have N consecutive blank lines, it removes N-1. If there's only 1 blank line, it is not removed. The example in the question therefore would not be handled. I'm using python on Windows, if that matters.

Comment: This script removes every after the 3rd line for my file.

Answer (score 49):

The `with` statement is excellent for automatically opening and closing files.

```
with open('myfile','r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        if not line.isspace():
            file.write(line)
```

Comment: +1 for use of "with" and good, pythonic iteration through lines, in addition to not mutating the good output lines.

Comment: It seems that you have to open myfile with `r+` flag instead of `rw` according to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: This solution seems like it would have buffering/overwrite problems for any file larger than the input buffer size. And if it doesn't, can somebody explain why?

Comment: This works fine for everything except removing blank lines already existing between the data in text file.

Comment: Python 3: ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode. Does this solution really work?

Answer (score 13):

```
import sys
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.isspace():
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Another way is

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    print "".join(line for line in f if not line.isspace())
```

Answer (score 5):

```
with open(fname, 'r+') as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
    fd.seek(0)
    fd.writelines(line for line in lines if line.strip())
    fd.truncate()
```

Answer (score 4):

I know you asked about Python, but your comment about Win and Linux indicates that you're after cross-platform-ness, and Perl is at least as cross-platform as Python.  You can do this easily with one line of Perl on the command line, no scripts necessary: `perl -ne 'print if /\S/' foo.txt`

(I love Python and prefer it to Perl 99% of the time, but sometimes I really wish I could do command-line scripts with it as you can with the -e switch to Perl!)

That said, the following Python script should work.  If you expect to do this often or for big files, it should be optimized with compiling the regular expressions too.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
file = open('foo.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    if re.search('\S', line): print line,
file.close()
```

There are lots of ways to do this, that's just one :)

Comment: You can do commandline scripts with python using the `-c` flag. Unfortunately you would have to use multiple lines (or seperation with ;) in order to read from standard input.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = """first line
... second line
... 
... third line
... """
>>> print '\n'.join([i for i in s.split('\n') if len(i) > 0])
first line
second line
third line
>>>
```

Comment: It depends on what "blank" means - this only works if blank means "nothing at all". If there are spaces between second line and third line, this will fail. Plus it needs to work on files :) But I like that you didn't have to import regexps :)

Comment: @Chirael - for that case you may add just len(i.strip()) > 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use below way to delete all blank lines:

```
with open("new_file","r") as f:
 for i in f.readlines():
       if not i.strip():
           continue
       if i:
           print i,
```

We can also write the output to file using below way:

```
with open("new_file","r") as f, open("outfile.txt","w") as outfile:
 for i in f.readlines():
       if not i.strip():
           continue
       if i:
           outfile.write(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the program below?

```
for line in open(filename):
    if len(line) > 1 or line != '\n':
        print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: On Linux/Windows based platforms where we have shell installed below solution may work as "os" module will be available and trying with Regex

Solution:

```
import os
os.system("sed -i \'/^$/d\' file.txt")
```

Comment: 1. This ignores a constraint of the question (i.e. use ONLY python) and 2. What if it isn't a POSIX system?

Comment: @Jared Smith
The Answer which i have posted is for LSB based systems which is superset of POSIX.

Comment: It'd be great if you could add more details/explanations to your answer.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: you're basically not using python :)

Comment: Doesn't work. sed: 1: "file.txt": command a expects \ followed by text

Answer (score 0):

**Using List Comprehension:**

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    print(result)
```

**Using Normal loop :**

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line.strip())
```