# Removing blank lines from json output to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, strip

I have a number of twitter json files that I want to search through for keywords and save those tweets with the keywords as csv.  In the process of trying to remove the blank lines, I've tried suggestions from similar posts such as this: [How to delete all blank lines in the file with the help of python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369440/how-to-delete-all-blank-lines-in-the-file-with-the-help-of-python)).  However, the blank lines continue to appear in my csv file.  Would anyone know what the problem is?

```
filenames = ["8may.json", "9may.json"]
open_files = map(open, filenames)

# keywords that you want to filter out; note that keywords should be in all lowercase
## change this to the keywords you want to use
keywords = ["test", "testing", "tester"]

# iterates though the files and does keyword matching; the tweet is only saved in csv if the tweet["text"] matches the keywords
for file in open_files:
    for line in file:
        if line.rstrip():
            try:
                # condition for searching through tweet["text"] with keywords
                if re.findall(r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(keywords), str(line).lower()):
                    tweets.append(json.loads(line))
            except:
                pass

for tweet in tweets:
    ids.append(tweet["id_str"])
    texts.append(tweet["text"])
    time_created.append(tweet["created_at"])
    retweet_counts.append(tweet["retweet_count"])
    in_reply_to_screen_name.append(tweet["in_reply_to_screen_name"])
    geos.append(tweet["geo"])
    coordinates.append(tweet["coordinates"])
    places.append(tweet["place"])
    # if there is no places data, then return None
    try:
        places_country.append(tweet["place"]["country"])
    except:
        places_country.append("None")
    lang.append(tweet["lang"])
    user_screen_names.append(tweet["user"]["screen_name"])
    user_followers_count.append(tweet["user"]["followers_count"])
    user_friends_count.append(tweet["user"]["friends_count"])
    user_statuses_count.append(tweet["user"]["statuses_count"])
    user_locations.append(tweet["user"]["statuses_count"])

print >> out, "ids,text,time_created,retweet_counts,in_reply_to,geos,coordinates,places,country,language,screen_name,followers,friends,statuses,locations"
rows = zip(ids,texts,time_created,retweet_counts,in_reply_to_screen_name,geos,coordinates,places,places_country,lang,user_screen_names,user_followers_count,user_friends_count,user_statuses_count,user_locations)

csv = writer(out)

for row in rows:
    values = [(value.encode('utf8') if hasattr(value, 'encode') else value) for value in row]
    csv.writerow(values)

out.close()
```

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? How are you *writing* the CSV file? The problem is most likely **not** with your JSON input.

Comment: have added how the csv file is written

Comment: How is `out` opened? And are you running this on Windows or a different platform?

Comment: `out = open("8maya.csv", "w")`

Comment: Once more: windows or a different OS?

Comment: Why parse JSON as text? If it's a valid JSON object then why not iterate through that and not worry about the space between?

Comment: oh sorry this is in windows

Comment: @mbs the intent is to save the json into a csv object that can be loaded into R.  trying to open the json in R leads to nested data frames which is a nightmare to process and analyse

Comment: @eugeneyan: right, this has nothing to do with how you are parsing your tweets; you need to open your files in binary mode instead.