# python removing blank lines and unwanted spaces

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python.I have a text file consisting of lots of blank lines.I need to remove these blank lines such that the existing lines will not be added/combines among each other.

text file

```
I am new to python


Python is a good programming language
```

Expected output:

```
I am new to python
Python is a good programming language
```

And my lines starts from second/nth line.I wanted to begin it from first line.Please help !Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: is the output printed to the screen ?? or rewritten to the file ?? to a new file ????

Comment: also, what do you mean by " And my lines starts from second/nth line.I wanted to begin it from first line " ??

Comment: @mlwn its rewritten to the file,it means that there will be lots of blank lines in the text file initially then the line starts

Comment: Duplicated with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369440/how-to-delete-all-blank-lines-in-the-file-with-the-help-of-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("in.txt" ) as f: # use with to close your files automatically
    lines = [line for line in f.read().split("\n") if line] # split on newline and remove "" using if x
    for line in lines:
        print line
I am new to python
Python is a good programming language
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to do this:

```
f = open(myfile,"r")
lines = filter(lambda x: x!="\n", f.readlines())
f.close()
print lines
```

`f.readlines` reads in all the lines from a file. The lambda-filter removes all occurrences in which that line is just `"\n"`.

Comment: but,its not removing blank lines in my file when I open it!

Comment: @adsqwqwe Yes it is. What does this output for you?